# Php while loop in WP not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to loop through posts in wordpress, but I am doing something wrong with my loop, since I get an error for it, not sure how to fix it. This is the loop:

```
  <?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : global $wp_query; $count = $wp_query->found_posts; ?>
      <?php  while ( $wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>


            <li> <?php echo get_the_title() ?></li>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I get an error

> page isn’t working
>
> superselma.dev is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR
>   500

**Updated**

When I have it like this:

```
<?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :?>
          <?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : global $wp_query; $count = $wp_query->found_posts; ?>
        <?php  while ( $wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>


              <li> <?php echo get_the_title() ?></li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Then it is working. So, the problem is in this line:

```
<?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : global $wp_query; $count = $wp_query->found_posts; ?>
```

This is the full code of the page:

```
<?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :?>
          <?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : global $wp_query; $count = $wp_query->found_posts; ?>
        <?php  while ( $wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>


              <li> <?php echo get_the_title() ?></li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($count > $per_page) :?>
            <div id="target-area"></div>

            <div class="small-centered small-10 medium-6 columns">
                <a id="get-more" class="sfk-btn button expand" href="javascript:getMore(<?php echo $cat_id; ?>, <?php echo $per_page; ?>, <?php echo $per_page; ?>)"><span>Klikk for mer</span></a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Ikke flere artikler', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Beklager, men ingen poster var funnet for dette arkivet.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-0 -->

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You have to wrap  get_the_title() function with <?php ?> tags

Comment: Its WordPress, you have to wrap almost everything in `<?php ?>` YUK

Comment: you get an error? maybe you want to share it with us?

Comment: Think that issue is somewhere else because I tested your code and everything working fine.

Comment: It can be a scope issue. There must be something wrong with $wp_query global variable. Are you sure that you are not overwriting before you access $wp_query?

Answer (score 1):

Declare (or if exists remove) *global $wp_query;* before if statement and remove *endif;* after *div class="small-centered small-10 medium-6 columns"*

Answer (score 1):

Remove  global $wp_query; from your code. It will start printing the title.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, could you look into php error log, if not defined config it in php.ini
It helps a lot, also set wordpress into debug mode.

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was closing the if loop before I should have. When I removed first `endif` statement then it worked.